# Mixing audio with Apple Watch

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, watchkit

**Question:** How can I get get text-to-speech working when delivered from the Apple Watch so that it does not stop my music and it gets delivered to a bluetooth device?

I am working on a running App that has an iPhone App and an Apple Watch App. I want to periodically read some information to the user.

With the iPhone App, I can do:

```
try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback, mode: .default, policy: .default, options: [.duckOthers, .mixWithOthers])
let text = "some text"
let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: text)
synthesizer.speak(utterance)
```

This will lower the volume of my other music, read the text, and then raise the volume. This will also work on my connected headsets.

However when I try to run this from my Apple Watch it is playing through the Watch speaker phone, not through my bluetooth connected devices.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60809649/avspeechsynthesizer-uses-apple-watchs-speaker-and-not-headset-as-output-channel) is related but the answer won't work in my case. If I try to use `.longFormAudio` I get this in the console:

```
2020-10-16 13:12:29.750696-0400 [...] [avas] AVAudioSession.mm:308:ValidateRouteSharingPolicyParameters: 0x3 category option(s) not supported in combination with AVAudioSessionRouteSharingPolicyLongFormAudio
audioSession properties weren't set because of an error.
```

If I remove `options: [.duckOthers, .mixWithOthers]` then no more console error, and the bluetooth picker in the Watch comes up but then I cannot keep bluetooth connected on my iPhone. Kinda pulling my hair out on this one.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am experiencing the exact same problem. 
I found out that if the music is not playing, the audio will play normally through the headphones, but as soon as I start playing music, the audio will come out through apple watch's speakers. I tried every combination possible, but there is still something missing.
The best I could do was to stop the music altogether, play my audio, but then I can't enable the music back again.

Comment: Nope unfortunately not. I’m pretty sure this is a limitation of the OS

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply!
I have given up for now. The best I could achieve was to stop music, play sound, resume music. It's not optimal, but it is something...

Comment: @tf.alves how did you achieve pausing and resuming the music from watch?

Comment: @Kushagra Unfortunately I ended up abandoning the project, since it was not possible to achieve most of the things I wanted to develop.
I can't recall how I played / paused the audio, but I recall it was not too reliable, as it would fail more often than not.